# Spring Data Mongo - Embed entities at the top-level

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following class (simplified example):

```
@Entity
public class Person {
  private PersonName personName;

  ...
}

@Embeddable
public class PersonName {
  private String name;
  ...
}
```

`PersonName` contains some validation and other information.

When I save `Person` to Mongo, `PersonName` is saved as:

```
{ 
  ... 
  "personName": { "name": "John Smith" },
  ...
}
```

Whilst I understand this behaviour makes sense in most cases, in this case, I'd prefer that it simply saved the name, ideally as "personName": "John Smith", rather than nesting the inner object.

Is there any way to achieve this (hopefully by adding an annotation)?

Comment: it's going to be as simple as having a member variable `private String personName` inside `Person` class.

Comment: Yeah, obviously that would work, but I want to achieve this without polluting the Person class with extra properties or changing PersonName to be a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always register [custom converters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.custom-converters) for a specific type. Something like:

```java
@WritingConverter
class PersonNameToStringConverter implements Converter<PersonName, String> {

    @Override
    public String convert(PersonName source) {
        return source.name;
    }
}

@ReadingConverter
class StringToPersonNameConverter implements Converter<String, PersonName> {

    @Override
    public PersonName convert(String source) {
        return new PersonName(source);
    }
}
```